# Validate models in django admin with inlines (when I save several models at the time)

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-admin

I'm maiking a quiz on django.
On the picture below you can see 3 models (Quiz, QuizQuestionQuizAnswer) on 1 page.
I used NestedStackedInline and NestedTabularInline for that.

I need to need validate quiz when I save of edit forms.
For example:

- I need to check if at least one answer is marked as correct.
- If answers more than one.
  etc

[image]

**models.py**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название теста', max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField('Описание', max_length=2000, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    pass_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text='Минимальный результат (в процентах) для прохождения теста',
                                             default=60,
                                             validators=[
                                                 MaxValueValidator(100),
                                             ])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', auto_now_add=True, )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Дата обновления', auto_now=True, )

    def get_quiz_question(self):
        return self.quizquestion_set.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class QuizQuestion(models.Model):
    """ Вопросы для квиза"""
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.CharField('Вопрос', max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', auto_now_add=True, )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Дата обновления', auto_now=True, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Тест'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Тесты'

class QuizAnswer(models.Model):
    """ Варианты ответов """
    question = models.ForeignKey(QuizQuestion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField('Варианты ответа', max_length=250)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField('Отметьте правильные', default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ответ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ответы'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Вариант ответа'
```

**admins.py**

```
from quiz.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inline.admin import NestedStackedInline, NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline


class AnswerInLine(NestedTabularInline):
    """ Делаем вложенную модель в админке"""
    model = QuizAnswer
    extra = 1


class QuestionInLine(NestedStackedInline):
    """ Делаем вложенную модель в админке"""
    model = QuizQuestion
    extra = 2
    inlines = [AnswerInLine]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass


class QuizAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    # добавляет эти поля в админку приложения
    # list_display = ('title','description','pass_score')
    model = Quiz
    inlines = [QuestionInLine]
    readonly_fields = ('owner', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        if not obj.pk:
            # Only set added_by during the first save.
            obj.owner = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)




class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", 'title')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')
    search_fields = ('title',)


# регистрирует модуль и его параметры
admin.site.register(Quiz, QuizAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to define a custom formset like below:

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from quiz.models import *


class AnswerModelForm(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizAnswer
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean(self):
        true_answer_count = 0
        answer_count = 0
        for form in self.forms:
            try:
                if form.cleaned_data.get("is_correct") is True:
                    true_answer_count += 1
                answer_count += 1
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        if true_answer_count > 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                ("A question can not have more than one correct answer")
            )
        if answer_count not in [2, 3, 4]:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                ("A question can have only 2, 3, 4 answers")
            )
        if true_answer_count == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                ("A question must have at least one correct answer")
            )
```

> You can easily count all the correct answers and the total number of
> answers to your question and implement your own validations with them

**And you definitely should add your own formset to your AnswerInLine like below:**

**admin.py**

```
from quiz.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from quiz.forms import *
from nested_inline.admin import NestedStackedInline, 
NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline


class AnswerInLine(NestedTabularInline):
    formset=AnswerModelForm
    """ Делаем вложенную модель в админке"""
    model = QuizAnswer
    extra = 1


class QuestionInLine(NestedStackedInline):
    model = QuizQuestion
    extra = 2
    inlines = [AnswerInLine]
#rest of your code...
```